# What pronouns make most sense when referencing the Trinity?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, words-of-jesus, god-the-father

The Trinity is 3 persons sharing 1 essence.

***They*** share ***It***.

(Where does the "He", "Him", "Me", "My" come from?)

Jesus uses plural personified pronouns when referencing himself and his Father.

John 14:23
King James Version

> 23 Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, and ***WE*** will come unto him, and make ***OUR*** abode with him.

- ***Therefore, if we are to follow our Master, should Trinitarians use plural personified pronouns to reference multiple persons of the Trinity?  For example: "I love God. They are my salvation."***
- ***If not, please explain why we use singular personified pronouns when speaking of 3 persons? If the deity is not a person, why not use singular non personified pronouns?***

Comment: _They_ (Father and Son) make _their_ abode with one who loves Christ. _They_ come in One Holy Spirit. For 'I and the Father are One (Spirit)'.

Comment: I do not love a nature, I love a Person. That Person encompasses Divine nature and human nature. I love Him.

Comment: Do you not love persons (plural)?  All the 3 persons of the nature? Them?

Comment: . . . .  and I love the Father who is revealed in the Son. And I love the Spirit of holiness through whom the Father and the Son abide within. (This is not arithmetic : this is spiritual experience.)

Comment: Ok... but we are now off topic of the pronouns of THEM.

Comment: We are ***on the topic*** of your question about (quote) _the 1 God_ (unquote).

Comment: Yes the 1 non personified nature.  So why personal singular pronouns throughout?

Comment: The nature is shared by three persons. It is not 'non personified'.

Comment: OR if 3 persons, why not plural personified pronouns like Jesus does?

Comment: Which is it @NigelJ?  3 persons? or 1 Nature?

Comment: Jesus said 'I and the Father are one'. One God.

Comment: 1 non personified Nature?  This is the 1 God?  Right?

Comment: Not at all. Jesus also said _Pneuma ho Theos_. 'Spirit the Deity. The oneness of the nature is due to the Holy Spirit.

Comment: These things must be experienced in order to understand them, They cannot be analysed at a distance. No further comment.

Comment: God is Spirit.  Jesus was speaking of the Father in context.  "Worship the Father in Spirit and Truth"

Comment: Are you asking about modern English usage, or something more fundamental? Keep in mind that in the original Greek scriptures (and in modern French, Spanish, etc.) the word for "he" is the same as the word for "it". ¶ I would say "my family *is*" and "it *is*" (singular), but "my children, wife, and I *are*", and "we *are*" (plural). ¶ Please give specific contrasting examples of how pronouns are used in the English Bible, and how you think they should be used instead, so that we can beter understand your question.

Comment: @RayButterworth It depends what you mean by the same word; Greek has masculine, feminine and neuter pronouns, which are distinct (at least in some cases) thus he can be distinguished from it. A separate but related issue is that grammatical gender may not match biological gender; e.g. ousia (substance) is feminine in Greek.

Comment: I don't know whether it will help or confuse the issue, but you could read [Genesis 1:1, REV Bible and Commentary](https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/Genesis/chapter1/1) concerning "elohim" as a uni-plural noun.

Comment: I noticed that all my comment replies to Nigel are hidden until expanded.  Can a mod un-hide my responses so that the comments make sense?  Why did someone do this?  Are not my replies to others concerning my question important to the discussion?

Answer (score 5):

The doctrine of the Trinity means that there is one God subsisting in 3 Persons. God is not 3 beings (tritheism) nor are Father, Son and Holy Spirit descriptions of mode/role (modalism) where there is no real distinction between them.

The Persons are plural; the essence/being is one; thus according to Trinitarianism, plural pronouns can be used when referencing the persons as in the verse cited above.
For example

> The Father and the Son are both glorified

But when referring to God essentially, singular would be use.

> God alone is good.

In other words, there are no special grammar rules. God, Father, Son, Holy Spirit are all singular masculine nouns and thus, *he*, *him* and *his* may all be used according to the sentence. They, their or them could be used only when 2 or 3 persons are explicitly referred to:

> The Father and Son sent their Spirit into the world

The term "God" (as discussed elsewhere) signifies either the Divine essence (singular) or could be used in reference to a single person (e.g. God the Father) hence singular. The term "God" never stands in for a plurality of persons and so you never would say "God are" nor "They are my salvation"

To use a sentence like "They are my salvation" with "they" referring to God would hint at a form of trithesim in that it would suggest that God means a collective of divine beings and that they are separate enough to not be one.

In so far as the Trinity or the Essence is referred rather than a particular person (that is, unqualified uses of "God"), masculine pronouns are used because the divinity is separate from his creation (so not feminine) and he has an intellect and will, that is, he is not an impersonal force (as the Philosopher's God would be). Each Person is co-equal and co-eternal hence equally God; thus, we must be cautious about thinking of the essence as though it is something *extra* to the persons, which is what the suggestion of using "it" for the essence would suggest. That would lead to sentences like "The Son loves God and it loves him"

Ultimately though, the question of pronouns only becomes challenging when one doesn't understand the terms person and essence as used in Trinitarian theology.

> Jesus uses plural personified pronouns when referencing himself and his Father.

Trinitarians use pronouns exactly as Jesus does and as grammar suggests. The fact that quantity can be said of a thing doesn't make it plural absolutely, simply nor grammatically.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147271/discussion-on-answer-by-eques-should-trinitarians-use-plural-pronouns-when-refer); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Please use chat for future communications

Answer (score -2):

> For example: "*I love God. They are my salvation.*"

Compare that (non-biblical) example with "*I love my family. It is what keeps me going.*".

Except for unitarians, when speaking of "God" in general, one is talking about a collective entity, like "family", which is singular.
When Jesus is speaking of "my Father", then two persons within "God" are distinguished, just as if I talked about "my wife and me" (plural).

Even in Hebrew, the name "elohim" is plural in form, but when referring to God it is treated as a singular noun (uni-plural).

"God" is a singular noun (regardless of whether one is Trinitarian, binitarian, or unitarian).
It's a matter of Greek grammar, not of doctrine.

Comment: Family is non personified by using the pronoun "it". God is using personified pronouns. Huge difference. Now if the family was personified in the context, the pronouns would be *they, we, our.*

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore. If this answer were in Greek, "family" would be represented by "she", not by the English "it". — If by "*God is using*" you are referring to Jesus's use of "we" to represent "my Father and I" in John 14:23, then I still really don't understand what your question is asking about. What pronoun should he have used to refer to his Father and his self? (Also, note that "our" in 14:23 doesn't appear in the original Greek.)

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore. I'm still hoping to see an example of God referring to God as plural, since that's what the question seems to imply that we should be doing. Jesus's referring to two individual members of God as plural doesn't count, precisely because they *are* two persons.

Comment: Let me try to explain better. Is God a single non personified nature/essence?  If so, then singular non personified pronouns should be used.  They are not.  Why not?  If God is 3 persons then a plural pronoun should be used as Jesus is using it in this case.  Why is this not common place?  Instead, singular personal pronouns are always used to speak of God but Trinitarians reject God as a single person.  Why do they use the one type of pronouns that make no sense with their theology?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore says "*Is God a single non personified nature/essence? If so, then singular non personified pronouns should be used.*". You then say "*They are not.*", yet you haven't provided any scripture that refers to God in the third person in any way other than singular.(And John 14:23 doesn't count. That is not talking about God (the singular family); that is Jesus talking specifically about his Father, and the plural pronoun "we" is appropriate for referring to the two persons.)

Comment: There are plural and singular pronouns and they can be either personal or non personal.   For some reason Trinitarians use personal singular pronouns for an essence/nature that is not a person.   YHWH should either be an "it" or a "they" according to the Trinity.  But Trinitarians still use "He" when referencing YHWH.  Jesus uses plural personal pronouns when referencing more than one person of the Trinity.  Why don't you?

Comment: In your example sentence, the antecedent of "it" is the idea of one's _love_ of the family.  It does not refer to any person, nor to the family itself.  I'm not sure that is what you had in mind, however.  Perhaps you would rather choose a different example.